# node.js requestretry plugin change url on retry

Tags: node.js, request

I have a Node.js project and I am using the [requestretry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requestretry) library to make repeated requests on 404 errors.

I am wondering if there is a way to change the url on a retry using a custom retryStrategy. For instance, if I wanted to ping a server https://somesite.com/id/{5-digit-id} and I was creating a random 5-digit integer, trying it and if it failed, I would want to generate another 5-digit integer and try that one, is there a way to change the url like that in between retries?

Comment: @AluanHaddad I am sorry, I don't see it. I see the custom retryStrategy and the callback function, but I am not sure how to change the URL for the next request. Could you tell me where in that documentation you see it possibly?

Comment: My bad. I see what you mean.